# Closing fullscreen menu after click the menu link

Tags: javascript, css, menu, fullscreen, hamburger-menu

I found some similar questions but I don't know how to apply them to my case...

This fullscreen menu works fine, however when clicking on a link and directing to the selected #id I would like it to close by itself. Could someone help me?

```
<div id="myNav" class="menu">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">open</a>
              <div class="menu-content">
                <a href="#lorem"><h2>lorem</h2></a>
                <a href="#ipsum"><h2>ipsum</h2></a>
                <a href="#dolor"><h2>dolor</h2></a>
              </div>
            </div>
    <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()"><ion-icon name="reorder-three-outline">close</span>
```

Here is the .js I'm using.

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}
```

Thank you so much for the help! ♥

Answer (score 0):

First add a  common class to the `<a>` elements

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#lorem"><h2>lorem</h2></a>
<a class="nav-link" href="#ipsum"><h2>ipsum</h2></a>
<a class="nav-link" href="#dolor"><h2>dolor</h2></a>
```

Then use js to add a event listener that executes the closeNav() function when user clicks on the `<a>` elements

```
let nav_link = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link");

for (k = 0; k < nav_link.length; k++) {
    nav_link[k].addEventListener("click", function() {
               closeNav();
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't works :( I put your js code in the same doc as my js, added a class to the <a> elements and nothing happens...